# Can't ssh to vagrant + virtualbox (from vmware)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, vmware

I now my setup is redundant but it's only for testing purposes.
I'm running `VMware fusion 8.5.5` on my laptop. Inside my VMware I've installed Centos 7:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
```

After that I've installed vagrant

```
vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.9.3
```

And also `virtualbox version 5.1.18 r114002`

But when I start a vagrant box I'm unable to ssh. Never. The OS of the box doesn't matter:

```
$ vagrant init bento/centos-7.2
$ vagrant up
```

I'm facing this error when I try to check the virtual box GUI but I would think it's not problem in my case. I just try to ssh.

```
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/centos-7.2'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/centos-7.2' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: test_default_1490853341673_52433
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is a bug in the virtual box version you're using. try downloading virtualbox 5.1.4